# Friends car seized

Tags: grammar

Lets say I was driving my friends set of wheels and the police seized it yesterday for inconsiderate driving.

Today, my friend complains:

> Why did you drive like a lunatic? Im going to have to pay loads of money to reclaim it."

I leap to my own defence saying:

> I would have hated this to happen.

Is the "would have hated" part grammatically correct? Or should I say" I hated this to happen"? I'm trying to say I hate the fact that your car was seized and I didn't want this to happen.

Comment: Why not simply "I hate that this happened," since it did? or "I would never have wanted this to happen and hate that it did."

Comment: _I  would have hated this to happen_ implies that it didn't actually happen.

Comment: You actually use "I hate the fact that your car was seized and I didn't want this to happen" in your last sentence.